# Custom Adapter: in the getView method, when convertView in received as a View variable, why do people, reassign it to another View object

Tags: java, android

So basically, I am following the free Udacity course on android by google.

in there when they get to

```
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

  View listItemView = convertView;  <------------- they assign convertView to a new view object, I want to know why, is it done like that.
```

please if you can answer the following questions, I am so sorry but I want to know the logic behind them.
1) public WordAdapter ( Context context, int resource, ArrayList words)
in the custom adapter constructor, 
are this variable incoming from when you initialize the ArrayAdapter?

2) and the super in the ArrayAdapter, sometimes I've seen people 
use this: super(context, resource, words);
and sometimes: super(context, 0, words);

why so? I am thinking the resource is not important here because when you set adapter, the resource becomes obvious.

I am so confused. please and thank you, I want to make my foundation knowledge strong.

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {


    int mResouce;
    Context mContext;

  public WordAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Word> words) {


            super(context, resource, words);
       mResouce  =resource;
            this.mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if (listItemView == null ){
                    listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }
            Word word = getItem(position);

            TextView view1 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
            TextView view2 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
            view1.setText(word.getDefaultTranslation());
            view2.setText(word.getMiwokTranslaton());


            return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Sorry. Won't do it again. I just thought I would be polluting if I ask so many individual questions, soon after signing up. Won't happen again.